# I keep getting an error from the vue compiler that ive neveer seen before

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

it seems to be one of my dependancies but i have no clue whats going on here and i cant find anything on the internet.
(i clearly need to know more about webpack)
any help is muchly appreciated

weirdly enough this only started happening when i cloned my repo on my work pc, i hadnt even made any changes

this is the error im getting from my console

```
 95% emitting

 WARNING  Compiled with 3 warnings                                                     2:06:09 PM

 warning  in C:/Users/1/Documents/GitHub/GFS/client/node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js

There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\1\Documents\GitHub\GFS\client\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\1\Documents\GitHub\GFS\client\node_modules\node-libs-browser\node_modules\punycode\punycode.js
* C:\Users\1\documents\github\gfs\client\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\1\documents\github\gfs\client\node_modules\vue\dist\vue.esm.js

 warning  in C:/Users/1/Documents/GitHub/GFS/client/node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js

There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\1\Documents\GitHub\GFS\client\node_modules\webpack\hot\emitter.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\1\Documents\GitHub\GFS\client\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?http://localhost:8082
* C:\Users\1\documents\github\gfs\client\node_modules\webpack\hot\emitter.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\1\documents\github\gfs\client\node_modules\webpack\hot\dev-server.js

 warning  in C:/Users/1/Documents/GitHub/GFS/client/node_modules/webpack/hot/log.js

There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* C:\Users\1\Documents\GitHub\GFS\client\node_modules\webpack\hot\log.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\1\Documents\GitHub\GFS\client\node_modules\webpack\hot nonrecursive /^\.\/log$/
* C:\Users\1\documents\github\gfs\client\node_modules\webpack\hot\log.js
    Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
    C:\Users\1\documents\github\gfs\client\node_modules\webpack\hot\dev-server.js
```

Comment: It's exactly what the error message says.  You've got some files in a folder named 'GitHub' and other files in a folder named 'github'.  Some filesystems can't tell that those are different, so you'll run into problems.

Comment: yes but i only have one folder called Github on my entire pc though, maybe some of my dependancies think that the folder name isnt capitalized?

Comment: This depends on how this path is being used. If you're sure you didn't explicitly specify `gfs` or `GFS` anywhere in import path, the problem is probably in third-party libs. You could avoid this by not using upper case in project dir names

Comment: i havent specified any of that anywhere, evrything is relative paths and i changed all my dir names to lowercase but im still getiing the erro because my documents folder is caitilized and i dont want to rename that, what else could it be?

Comment: The error message shows you have multiple cases of mixed capitalization: `C:\Users\1\Documents\GitHub\GFS` and `C:\Users\1\documents\github\gfs`.

Comment: shout out to daniel and estus for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it turns out, all i had to do was re navigate to the project dir from my terminal and i had to make sure i was using the correct capitlization there

(git bash sucks)

i used `../Documents/github...` insteda of `../documents/github...`

thank you internet.
yall have a great day and thanks for the help